# using cuda to run one thread on gpu, why was the gpu load so high?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Below is my gpu information:

```
Device 0: "GeForce GT 440"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.0 / 7.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 1536 MBytes (1610612736 bytes)
  ( 3) Multiprocessors, ( 48) CUDA Cores/MP:     144 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1189 MHz (1.19 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             800 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              192-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 393216 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535),
3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Mo
del)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
```

The cuda code is quite simple:

```
__global__ void kernel(float *d_data)
{
    *d_data = -1;
    *d_data = 1/(*d_data);
    *d_data = (*d_data) / (*d_data);
}
int main()
{
    float *d_data;
    cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(float));
    while (1)
        kernel << <1, 1 >> >(d_data);
    float data;
    cudaMemcpy(&data, d_data, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("%f\n",data);
    return 0;
}
```

then run the code, I get the gpu load from GPU-Z is 99%!!

GPU-Z:  http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/

Am I missing something? How to understand the gpu load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPU "load" is just a measure of the proportion of time that the gpu is busy, divided by the total time interval.

So if your program runs for 1.0 second, and the kernel takes 0.8 second to run, the GPU load for that interval is going to be 80%.  With GPU-Z, since this number is updated periodically, if your kernel is running during the entire period of update, it will appear to be approximately 100% busy.

Since, for your given code, your kernel is running all the time, the GPU load should be close to 100%.  It does not matter what the kernel is doing.  If the kernel is running, the GPU is busy, and that is how load is measured.

Comment: GPU "load" is just a measure of the proportion of time that the gpu is busy, divided by the total time interval. It means the "load" has nothing to do with the size of hardware source gpu has been used, right?

Comment: Here is another problem, I have compiled an algorithm which will run on gpu by using only one thread `(<<<1,1>>>)` calls "app". Then I use the script to run it: `./app`, it took me 175.95 seconds. Next, I change the script : ./app & ./app &.

Comment: That's right.  I would expect that your program, which runs a kernel continually, would show ~99% load on any GPU that it is run on.

Comment: The script will launch two "app" at the same time, they took me 353.41s and 353.25s respectively. Before this test, I believed that the time of running two "app" would be close to the time running one "app", the reason is gpu can run the two "app" concurrently. Can you give me some tips about this?

Comment: Two CUDA applications, launched from different host processes (as is true for your example) cannot share the GPU.  They will serialize.  First one kernel will run then the other.  If you have new questions, please post new questions on SO. I'm not going to continue a dialog in the comments.